# Overlay synchronization with `\setcounter{beamerpauses}` and the `\pause` command

Tags: beamer

I'm very new to the wonderful `beamer` class.

I am attempting to create synchronized overlays by resetting the `beamerpauses` counter.

I do not understand why the `\pause` command does not play smooth with this practise.

I came across the following workaround, 
      \uncover<+>{}  % or \only<+>{} or ... ?

but I would rather understand what is going on with pauses !

### My example

*(Uncomment line 15 `\pause`to break)*

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\Number{3}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Why does this break when commenting the pause ?}

  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{.48\textwidth}
      \foreach \k in {1,...,\Number}%
      {%
        \only<+>{Left overlay \k}%
      }
      %\pause         %%%%%%%%%%%%% Why does this pause break everything ?
      %\uncover<+>{}  %%%%%%%%%%%%% but this works ...!
    \column{.48\textwidth}
      \setcounter{beamerpauses}{1}
      \foreach \k in {1,...,\Number}%
      {%
        \only<+>{Right overlay \k}%
      }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `\pause` is a very crude command, for all things where you need a bit more fine control, commands such as `\uncover<>{}`, `\only<>{}`, `\visible<>{}` etc. work better [as you already noticed yourself].

As far as I understand your code, the `\pause` does not work because it adds another overlay before the second column is read -- so on the first three overlays beamer does not "see" the second column, just know how much space it should reserve. Afterwards it tries to add the second column, but as all the text on it is only displayed on the first three overlays, you get an empty page. You can maybe see this in the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\Number{3}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Why does this break when commenting the pause ?}

  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{.48\textwidth}
      \foreach \k in {1,...,\Number}%
      {%
        \only<+>{Left overlay \k}%
      }
      \pause         %%%%%%%%%%%%% Why does this pause break everything ?
      %\uncover<+>{}  %%%%%%%%%%%%% but this works ...!
    \column{.48\textwidth}
      \setcounter{beamerpauses}{1}
      \foreach \k in {1,...,\Number}%
      {%
        \only<+>{Right overlay \k}%
      }
      \only<5>{overlay 5}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```